# how to solve this css issue?

Tags: html, css

I am having some css issues...

When you hover over a product from [here](http://laptopsisland.com/shop/c/laptops/), you can see 'show now'..

But when you hover over the product from [here](http://yourinspirationweb.com/demo/maya/home-version-v/), you can see 'Addto Cart' and you also see some black background for 'Add To Cart' which I am not understanding..

May I know what still I have to add in CSS..?

**here is my code that displays products:**

```
<!-- Product List -->
<div class="pl">
  [product.each]

  <div class="t1 col3">



    <ul class="products ribbon">

      <li class="product">


        <a href="[product.link]">

          <div class="thumbnail">

              <img width="150" height="150" src="[product.image direct='1' tag='0']" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="[product.name]" title="[product.name]">    

              <div class="thumb-shadow"></div>

              <strong class="below-thumb">[product.name]</strong>  

            </div>


          <span class="price">

            <span class="amount">

              <?php if ($product->saleprice > 0 &&  $product->saleprice < $product->price) { ?>

                    <div class="prc">
                <small>
                   <span style="text-decoration: line-through; color:blue;">[product.currency mode='sign'][product.price]</span>&nbsp&nbsp
                   <span style="font-weight: bold; color:red;">[product.currency mode='sign'][product.saleprice]</span>
                </small>
                    </div>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <div class="prc">
                <small>
                  <span style="font-weight: bold; color:blue;">[product.currency mode='sign'][product.price]</span>
                </small>
                    </div>    

                <?php } ?>                


              </span>

            </span>

          </a>



          <div class="buttons" style="opacity: 0; visibility: visible; overflow: hidden; height: 41px; ">
                <a href="[product.link]"  class="add-to-cart add_to_cart_button product_type_simple" style="position: relative; top: -41px; ">SHOP NOW</a>
           </div>      


      </li>    


    </ul>



  </div>  <!-- t1 col3 #end --> 


      [/product.each]
      <div class="clearingdiv"> </div>

 </div>
<!-- /Product List -->
```

**so, please tell me what am I missing..? you can find CSS code in source code...**

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you stealing other people's source code?

Comment: 'Stealing' is a bit harsh, I know (outside of blogs, A List Apart, CSS Play and a few others) that the way *I* learn and improve is by looking at others' CSS...

Comment: The title to this question is not very descriptive - you should change it so that it gives more information about your problem

Comment: Nice question title, what's next "Issue?!?!" , that would be great...

Answer (score 0):

They have used a [background image](http://yourinspirationweb.com/demo/maya/wp-content/themes/maya/images/product-ribbon.png).

In your case you need to set a background to `.buttons` or the anchor in there.

BTW: please stop using inline-stylsheets; use a separate `<style>` block or an external CSS file instead. That way, your CSS is much easier to read and understand.